# PHP string in a function name

Tags: php, string, function

How to put PHP string in a function name?

```
for ($i=1;$i<10;$i++) { 
    function my_function_$i() {
    //Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '('        
        include($i.'.php');
    }
}
```

*UPDATE:*

OK. closed this question, I shall study for more.

Comment: explain a bit more.. what you are really looking for?

Comment: @user973254, I do not want to copy parse the same code. just a little difference. why a down vote? if my question is easier for you, why not help me out?

Comment: Don't understand why people down vote questions that just indicate someone is new to a language..

Comment: @Nico, ok, i am not mind down vote. but I should know, how to work code in this case. maybe as `Col. Shrapnel` said, a `regular function`, maybe `DaveRandom` said the `eval` way. Finally, I do not want to turn back for it is impossible, I believe it should have a way to work in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Please add some more of your code, or describe how you've structured it and how you think the above will help you. Where will you want to call those functions? What are you trying to achieve? In what way does writing `my_function_1()` involve less copy-pasting than writing `include('1.php')`, or `my_function(1)`?

Comment: @Nico because those who new to language insists on their wrong setup and refuse to learn the right way.

Comment: @Col And what's the "right way" to learn exactly? I like to learn by writing code and seeing if I can figure out a way to do something, which is what cj333 seems to be doing too...

Comment: @ Nico: I downvoted because the question is not likely to be useful for future visitors, quite the contrary, they may get an idea that this is the right way to do something. In it's current form the question is nearly useless. If the OP could say what he was trying to achieve people could really help him and future visitors with similar problems. In that case I would change my vote.

Comment: As for the right way to learn, it definitely includes correcting your mistakes once they are pointed out.

Answer (score 8):

there is something utterly wrong with your architecture if you come to a question like this.
it seems you do not understand what functions are for.

1. there should be no functions like `my_function_$i()` but **one** function `my_function($i)`
2. There should be no enumerated includes as well. What are these php files for?

Comment: so, it is impossible write string in a a function name?

Comment: it is possible but you don't need it for sure. and you have to learn regular functions first.

Comment: I have not found a example to write regular in function name. excuse me for my hard head.

Comment: cj333: The point Col. Shrapnel is making is that you probably shouldn't be calling separate functions, but in stead calling the same function with different arguments.

Comment: @Nico, not quiet think it by myself. I need a shorter code. do not want to write more, in the real case, I still have some `$i` in the function, for a question, not parse them all.

Comment: @cj333 It sounds like you would be better off asking a more general question about the architecture of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out - maybe what you're looking for

http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

from that page:

```
<?php
$newfunc = create_function('$a,$b', 'return "ln($a) + ln($b) = " . log($a * $b);');
echo "New anonymous function: $newfunc\n";
echo $newfunc(2, M_E) . "\n";
// outputs
// New anonymous function: lambda_1
// ln(2) + ln(2.718281828459) = 1.6931471805599
?>
```

Comment: Anonymous functions would work, but it's probably just going to lead to more confusion and frustration for someone who's learning the basics of the language..

Comment: You need a hug Col. Shrapnel? :)

Comment: @Col - Shame about your comments... Maybe we're all learning here. No need to be rude. I'm sure you don't know everything about everything ... isn't that the point?

Comment: it is not about knowledge. it is just about common sense. Almost every answer on this site is written mechanically, triggered by some keyword in the question. You see the "variable function name" - here comes an answer. But why noone tries to get THE MEANING of the question? To consider if the question okay to answer?

Comment: @Col Shrapnel that's a side effect of the reputation system. You can't change human psychology by ranting at random people.

Comment: @Nico - It's not about points or ranking... there maybe a situation where this could be needed does Col know everything about everything?  Stackoverflow is about helping others... or did I get that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is a horrible thing to do. Consider using [closures](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), or [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php), or passing `$i` as an argument.

Secondly - the only way I can think of to do this (but for Christ's sake, *don't*) is with `eval()`:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    eval("function my_function_$i() {
        include('$i.php');
    }");
}
```

Comment: +1, eval can work, but still little error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER` in line `include('$i.php');`.  I modify to `include(".'$i.".php');` to avoid the fault, but not sure it is safe or no...

Comment: @cj333 It will work but it's a BAD solution. If you go down that path you are probably shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @cj333 Agreed with Nico, I'm not saying do it (indeed, I specifically said *don't* do it) I'm just saying that it can be done. As soon as you see `eval()`, it's probably a sign of something you shouldn't do.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can use eval for do like this:

```
for ($i=1;$i<10;$i++) { 
    eval('function myfunc_'.$i.'(){echo '.$i.';}'); 

}

myfunc_5();

//Output
//5
```

Comment: Please don't... That would be a horrible, horrible way to solve a fairly simple problem.